# Playing soundcard input to soundcard output in Python

Tags: python, linux, audio, pyaudio, portaudio

Does anyone know if there's a way to play a certain soundcard input to an output in the same soundcard using Python? (or any other language whatsoever)

If so, would it be possible to write a script that reads an input of a soundcard and bounces it to an output on the same card and, if this input is silent for more than ten minutes, reroutes it to the output?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**: Answers for *any* operating systems are welcome. Windows or linux distros preferred, OSX also acceptable.

Comment: I think this will depend on your OS so you should edit your question and include which one you're running

Comment: @notorious.no will do

Answer (score 2):

[pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) has a method called non-blocking callback in which input (such as microphone) is directly routed to output (speakers / headphones) as is , meaning with no manipulation can be done over incoming stream.
Not sure if thats what you are looking for.
If you need to manipulate stream before you write (or send to putput) then you have @rewolf's answer.

Source Code from [site](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/).

```
"""
PyAudio Example: Make a wire between input and output (i.e., record a
few samples and play them back immediately).

This is the callback (non-blocking) version.
"""

import pyaudio
import time

WIDTH = 2
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.1)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Picking devices**

You can get a list of supported devices the PyAudio API:

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
host_info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)    
device_count = host_info.get('deviceCount')

# can iterate through devices and check their info:
p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, device_index)

{'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.01, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.0029024943310657597, 'maxInputChannels': 2L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 0L, 'index': 0L, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.1, 'maxOutputChannels': 0L, 'name': u'Built-in Microphone', 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.013061224489795919}
```

**Recording and Playing, Realtime**

Recording can be done by opening and reading from an input stream, and this can simultaneously be played through an output stream.
Devices can be selected using `input_device_index` or `output_device_index`

For example, this records and plays immediately:

```
import pyaudio

BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
DURATION = 5
SAMPLE_RATE = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

input_stream = p.open(
    format=pyaudio.paInt16,
    channels=2,
    rate=SAMPLE_RATE,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=BUFFER_SIZE,
    input_device_index=0
    )

output_stream = p.open(
    format=pyaudio.paInt16,
    channels=2,
    rate=SAMPLE_RATE,
    output=True
    )

for i in xrange(int(SAMPLE_RATE / BUFFER_SIZE * DURATION)):
    data = input_stream.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
    output_stream.write(data)

input_stream.stop_stream()
input_stream.close()
output_stream.stop_stream()
output_stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

I wasn't quite following your exact question about bouncing the audio between cards etc. But I'm sure you can figure that out from what I've mentioned above.

Hope this helps

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks! My question is  specifically how to route a given input directly to an output. The analog analogue would be essentially taking an electric guitar and switching what amp it goes through.